# What is an infostore in SAP BusinessObjects?

Tags: business-objects

I am confused what InfoStore is and what it consists of.

When I request `http://localhost:6405/biprws/infostore` using GET method,
I get the JSON-formatted response consisting of Alert Notifications, calendars, categories, etc.

What does this mean?

What does an InfoStore consist of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The infostore consists of *infoobjects*. An *infoobject* represents a report, folder, universe, user, event, calendar, server, service, server group, user group, relationship, category, publication, object package, destination plugin, hyperlink, license key, security plugin, and many other things.

In short, the infstore contains everything in a BusinessObjects cluster.

Comment: Iam actually new to this business objects concept, So can you tell me what data will be stored in each infoobject? @Joe

Comment: It's metadata.  So a user object would have properties such as user name, full name, password, email address, group membership, etc.  Each infoobject kind will have different metadata associated with it.  You're seeing a portion of those properties when you perform REST queries.

Comment: Got it, where does the actual data(not metadata) will be stored? @Joe

Comment: Reports, universes, and generated files from schedules are stored in teh File Repository System; by default this is located in a directory on the BO server.

Comment: i have understood now @joe